# Is use of broke correct in this sense?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

I know the meaning of **broken**, based on this Cambridge Dictionary's definition:

> [ before noun ]
> Suffering emotional pain that is so strong that it changes the way you
> live, usually as a result of an unpleasant event: He was a **broken** man
> after his wife died.

But I want to use it to say that *when "xyz" happened last year, it **broke** me*.

I couldn't find enough results online to show that broke also means same. In fact it showed results related to *no money*. Since broke is also a form of same verb, can it be used like this?

Or I must write *it made me broken* or something else (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you put it, "it broke me", is fine. I looked for the phrase at Google books, and all but one of the hits on the first page had the sense you are looking for (that it caused me severe emotional damage):

[Google books "it broke me"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20broke%20me%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpqqSQ4IzrAhUGHs0KHWbmAXMQ_AUoAXoECA0QCQ&biw=1252&bih=739)

Comment: Thanks. Also I was wondering if "i was broken after his death" is correct, "I have been broken after his death" also correct?

Comment: "I was..." seems more natural. Try some of those phrases at Google books. It will give you better examples of usage than simple search.